# Can I use wildcards when deleting Google Cloud Tasks?

Tags: google-cloud-tasks

I'm very new to [Google Cloud Tasks](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/).

I'm wondering, is there a way to use wildcards when [deleting a task](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/reference/rest/v2beta3/projects.locations.queues.tasks/delete)? For example, if I potentially had 3 tasks in queue using the following ID naming structure...

1. id-123-task-1
2. id-123-task-2
3. id-123-task-3

Could I simply delete `id-123-task-*` to delete all 3, or would I have to delete all 3 specific ID's every time? I guess I'm trying to limit the number of required API invocations to delete everything related to 'id-123'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I use wildcards when deleting Google Cloud Tasks?

As of today, wildcards are not supported within Google Cloud Tasks. I can not confirm that you could pass the Google Cloud Task's ID as you mentioned `id-123-task-*` will delete all the tasks.

Nonetheless, if you are creating tasks for an **specific purpose in mind**, you could create a separate queue for this kind of tasks.

Not only you will win in **terms of organizing your tasks**, but when you would like to delete all, you will only need to **purge all tasks from the specified queue** making only 1 API invocation.

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/taskqueue/push/deleting-tasks-and-queues#purging_all_tasks_from_a_queue) you could see how to purge all tasks from the specified queue, and also [how to delete tasks and queues.](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/taskqueue/push/deleting-tasks-and-queues)

Also, I attached the [API documentation](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.locations.queues/purge) in case you need further information about purging queues in Cloud Tasks.

As stated [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/taskqueue/push/deleting-tasks-and-queues#purging_all_tasks_from_a_queue), take into account that if you purge all the tasks from a queue:

> Do not create new tasks immediately after purging a queue. Wait at least a second. Tasks created in close temporal proximity to a purge call will also be purged.

Also, if you are using **named tasks**, as stated [here:](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/manage-cloud-task-scaling#named_tasks)

> You can assign your own name to a task by using the name parameter. However, this introduces significant performance overhead, resulting in increased latencies and potentially increased error rates associated with named tasks. These costs can be magnified significantly if tasks are named sequentially, such as with timestamps.

As a consequence, if you are using **named tasks**, the documentation recommends using a well-distributed prefix for task names, such as a hash of the contents.

I think this is the best solution if you would like **to limit the amount of API calls.**

I hope it helps.

Comment: Very interesting solution, thank you. I'll reach the 1000 total queue limit too quickly however as I would be generating about 1000 new queues per hour. :( https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/quotas Thank you for answering the wildcard question however, that was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I am glad the solution work out! As for the limit is concerned, you could automatically set a limit within your API, and when it arrives at X number of queues, just start purging until you could create more of them. Nonetheless, if you think that maybe you will need more than 1000 queues, you could request a quota increase [here](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/quotas#quota_increases). I hope it helps.